# Do HTML input tags require an id or name?

Tags: javascript, html, riot.js

I have a riot tag which contains a loop, shown below. This loop is inside another riot loop (maybe important?). After upgrading to riot version 2.3.0, the page become slow and unresponsive. The release notes stated riot loops were slower but more reliable.

I found that when I remove the ids from the input tags the page was again responsive. With no id on the inputs I thought I would re-write the onclick methods to identify which node was clicked some other way.

This didn't work as it appears my onclick methods aren't being registered. So my question: Is it illegal to have an input with no id or name? or is it likely I am doing something else wrong?

```
<div class="card-action">
   <div each={field in obj.fields} class="col s6" no-reorder>
       <a>{ field.label }</a>
       <form action='#'>
        <input type="radio" id="always-{field.id}" checked={ parent.currentDisplayAlways[field.name] } onclick={ parent.onInterestingFieldCheckboxClicked }>
        <label>Always</label>

        <input type="radio" id="conditional-{field.id}" checked={ parent.currentDisplayConditional[field.name] } onclick={ parent.onInterestingFieldCheckboxClicked }>
        <label>Conditional</label>

        <input type="radio" id="never-{field.id}" checked={ parent.currentDisplayNever[field.name] } onclick={ parent.onInterestingFieldCheckboxClicked }>
        <label>Never</label>
        </form>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It is likely you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: Its legal to have input without id or name but that's probably not the reason why your page was unresponsive

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Thanks! I put the unresponsiveness down to the changes riot made to loops.

Comment: It's not illegal but name is useful if you want to group radios or send the form, and ID is useful if you need to uniquely identify the input in a label or JS.

Comment: this sounds like it is a problem specifically with riot.js and has nothing to do with *HTML* itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can bind method and add your ID or object in the method. You can use event if you want to find clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

It is **definitely** legal to have an HTML `input` without a `id` or `name` attribute. To identify which node was clicked without an `id` in Javascript, you could pass the function that you want to call the `this` keyword, which is pretty much the entire DOM Object for that element as would have been retrieved by `document.getElementById()`. So, the function would look like so:

```
function firedAfterClicked(el) {
   alert(el.checked); //Whatever you want it to do
}
```

And an input would look like so:

```
<input type="radio" checked={ parent.currentDisplayNever[field.name] } onclick="firedAfterClick(this)">
```

That code calls the `firedAfterClick` function whenever it is clicked, and passes it the input as a DOM element, courtesy to the `this` keyword.

However, I have a feeling that the true problem is something else to do with your Riot code. Taking out the `id` attributes seems like more of a temporary workaround than a real solution to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this and while the inputs showed onclick method on inspection, they still didn't work (no alert). Your right, it is a workaround.